# Reading Dictionaries from csv files

Tags: python, json, csv, dictionary

One of my cells in my csv has the following data:

```
'{{" Colour" : " Orange (OG)"," Open, post termination (Yes/No)" : " No"," Pack Cont." : " 1"," PART DESCRIPTION" : " BSWTOOL12-PL-OG"," Product Group" : " Hot Knives, Installation Tools & Accessories"," Short Description" : " Installation Tool, 1/2" Split Wrap Braided Sleeving, 1/pkg"},{" " : "None"," Bundle ∅ max." : " 12.7mm"," Diameter (D)" : " 12.7mm"," Nominal ∅" : " 12.7mm"," Nominal ∅" : " 0.5""," ∅ D" : " 0.50""},{" CE Certification" : " No"," CSA Certified" : " No"," Halogenfree" : " Yes"," Material" : " Plastic (PL)"," Specifications" : " "," UL Listed (US and Canada)" : " No"," UL Recognized (US and Canada)" : " No"},{" GTIN-13 / EAN" : " 4031026432168"," Packaging 1 - Weight (kg)" : " 0.014kg"},{" ETIM 6.0" : " EC001182"," ETIM 7.0 Key" : " EC001182"," UNSPSC Key" : " 39131602"}}'
```

I tried `json.loads()` and `ast.literal_eval()` for that cell but both of them throw an error.

json.loads() throws the following:

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

ast.literal_eval() gives invalid syntax error.

PS: in the dictionary if you see an additional **"** character, that is to signify inches so technically the data can't be changed.

Comment: You need to escape embedded `"` inside strings. If you don't do that, there's no way for `json.loads()` or `ast.literal_eval()` to figure out which quotes are delimiters and which are for inches.

Comment: You need to fix this at the source, they need to use `json.dumps()` when creating the CSV>

Comment: To process this as a set of python dictionaries, I'd replace the "outer" double-quotes with single quotes. Then you don't have to escape any "inner" double-quotes.  You'll also want to figure out a plan for that "empty" key value '{" " : "None"', I don't think that's legit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few issues right away:

1. You have double braces `{{` and `}}`, which is not a valid JSON object (or Python dict).
2. You have unescaped quotes in string literals, such as:
   `" Installation Tool, 1/2" Split Wrap Braided Sleeving, 1/pkg"`
3. The outer braces seem to denote a JSON array or Python list rather than a dictionary.

Try taking the string and converting it to valid JSON to see what transformations you'll need to apply.

I suspect another thing you'll want to do is strip whitespace from dictionary keys (and possibly values too).

I strongly recommend you do not eval the string, as this executes code, which can lead to security issues depending on how you intend to consume this data.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, it's not a valid json. Use this for comparsion and see if you can convert your csv or string to match. Then it'll work:

```
import json

jsonStr_error = '{{" Colour" : " Orange (OG)"," Open, post termination (Yes/No)" : " No"," Pack Cont." : " 1"," PART DESCRIPTION" : " BSWTOOL12-PL-OG"," Product Group" : " Hot Knives, Installation Tools & Accessories"," Short Description" : " Installation Tool, 1/2" Split Wrap Braided Sleeving, 1/pkg"},{" " : "None"," Bundle ∅ max." : " 12.7mm"," Diameter (D)" : " 12.7mm"," Nominal ∅" : " 12.7mm"," Nominal ∅" : " 0.5""," ∅ D" : " 0.50""},{" CE Certification" : " No"," CSA Certified" : " No"," Halogenfree" : " Yes"," Material" : " Plastic (PL)"," Specifications" : " "," UL Listed (US and Canada)" : " No"," UL Recognized (US and Canada)" : " No"},{" GTIN-13 / EAN" : " 4031026432168"," Packaging 1 - Weight (kg)" : " 0.014kg"},{" ETIM 6.0" : " EC001182"," ETIM 7.0 Key" : " EC001182"," UNSPSC Key" : " 39131602"}}'
jsonStr_works = r'[{" Colour" : " Orange (OG)"," Open, post termination (Yes/No)" : " No"," Pack Cont." : " 1"," PART DESCRIPTION" : " BSWTOOL12-PL-OG"," Product Group" : " Hot Knives, Installation Tools & Accessories"," Short Description" : " Installation Tool, 1/2\" Split Wrap Braided Sleeving, 1/pkg"},{" " : "None"," Bundle ∅ max." : " 12.7mm"," Diameter (D)" : " 12.7mm"," Nominal ∅" : " 12.7mm"," Nominal ∅" : " 0.5\""," ∅ D" : " 0.50\""},{" CE Certification" : " No"," CSA Certified" : " No"," Halogenfree" : " Yes"," Material" : " Plastic (PL)"," Specifications" : " "," UL Listed (US and Canada)" : " No"," UL Recognized (US and Canada)" : " No"},{" GTIN-13 / EAN" : " 4031026432168"," Packaging 1 - Weight (kg)" : " 0.014kg"},{" ETIM 6.0" : " EC001182"," ETIM 7.0 Key" : " EC001182"," UNSPSC Key" : " 39131602"}]'
jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr_works)
```

**Output:**

```
print(jsonData[0])
{' Colour': ' Orange (OG)', ' Open, post termination (Yes/No)': ' No', ' Pack Cont.': ' 1', ' PART DESCRIPTION': ' BSWTOOL12-PL-OG', ' Product Group': ' Hot Knives, Installation Tools & Accessories', ' Short Description': ' Installation Tool, 1/2" Split Wrap Braided Sleeving, 1/pkg'}
```